# Java sort a list of pairs using both indexes

Tags: java, java-8

I want to sort a `List<Pair<Long, Long>> list = new ArrayList<Pair<Long, Long>>();` according to both the indexes, firstly according to first index and if first indexes are equal then according to second index using Java 8 lambda function.

I could easily sort only by first index as:
`Collections.sort(list,(o1, o2) -> o1.first < o2.first ? -1:0);`

If I want to sort according to both the indexes
`Collections.sort(list,(o1, o2) -> o1.first < o2.first ? -1 : o1.first == o2.first ? (o1.second < o2.second ? -1 : 0) : 0);`
But I don't think its the right way to do it. Can someone please provide a better syntax?

Pair definition:

```
    class Pair<Type1, Type2> {
        Type1 first;
        Type2 second;

        Pair(Type1 f, Type2 s) {
            this.first = f;
            this.second = s;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return "(" + this.first + ", " + this.second + ")";
        }
    }
```

Comment: You can tell that a comparator is broken when you see that it sometimes returns a negative number but never a positive number. That obviously breaks the symmetry requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Collections.sort` along with a comparator construction function like this:

```
Collections.sort(list, 
    Comparator.comparing((Pair<Long, Long> p) -> p.first)
        .thenComparing(p -> p.second));
```

**Update**

Alternatively, as suggested in the comment below you could use `List.sort` and it is a bit more succinct than the utility method used above.

```
list.sort(Comparator.comparing((Pair<Long, Long> p) -> p.first)
    .thenComparing(p -> p.second));
```

Comment: You can also use `list.sort(…)` directly.

Comment: Of course, good catch. Sometimes it's confusing when the library authors provide different approaches of doing the same thing. However the suggested approach is much more succinct and worth mentioning as an update. Would the implementation specific to `List` use some specific optimizations over the utility method `Collections.sort`?

Comment: In case of the commonly used `ArrayList`, the `sort` method has been overridden to skip the copying step of the `default` method, however, since [Java 8, update 20](https://bugs.java.com/bugdatabase/view_bug.do?bug_id=8032636) the `Collections.sort(…)` method just delegates to `list.sort(…)`, so you get the advantages of specialized implementations automatically. So, both will do the same, but `list.sort(…)` is just simpler.

Comment: Yes, list.sort is just more readable I guess. Thanks for the detailed explanation.